# How to count element of one controller into another

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i've a question to ask for my mvc project...
i have two controllers: `Giurisprudenza` e `GiurisprudenzaNode`, these controllers implement an index with the list of elements and a crud system to add/edit/remove elements. In the `Girusiprudenza` view page every element has a button that return you into the relative `GiurisprudenzaNode` page, with the list of elements contained into the primary element.
I would like to insert a label next to every element of the list in `Giurisprudenza` that say how many elements there are into that single primary element, but i don't know how to do that count... Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you dont need two controllers or two different view .
For this you need to follow below steps.

1. Create a viewModel (Customize mix of both models)
2. add custom property in you this viewmodel for counts
3. create new view for this ViewModel class .

Let  me know if you need code snippet for this.
[View Model from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3)